# Agda 2.4.0.x regression on termination check

Tags: agda

The following code termination checks on Agda 2.3.2.2 but not on 2.4.0.x:

```
open import Data.Nat
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

+-comm : ∀ a b → a + b ≡ b + a
+-comm zero zero = refl
+-comm zero (suc b) = cong suc (+-comm zero b) -- this recursive call is red
+-comm (suc a) zero = cong suc (+-comm a zero)
+-comm (suc a) (suc b) rewrite 
    +-comm a (suc b)
  | +-comm b (suc a) -- and also this one
  | +-comm a b = refl
```

What would be the simplest and least obtrusive way to get rid of the warnings under the newer Agda version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some changes in how the termination checker works (as far as I know, new algorithm was used to make the `--termination-depth` option obsolete).

The first recursive call is actually fine. It's structurally recursive, but I have no idea why it's being marked.

It's the second one that is causing problems. If you make it structurally recursive, Agda stops complaining. And the fix is actually fairly simple:

```
+-comm : ∀ a b → a + b ≡ b + a
+-comm zero zero = refl
+-comm zero (suc b) = cong suc (+-comm zero b)
+-comm (suc a) zero = cong suc (+-comm a zero)
+-comm (suc a) (suc b) rewrite
         +-comm a (suc b)
  | sym (+-comm (suc a) b)
  |      +-comm a b = refl
```

Comment: Thank you, nice answer as always. I had other places in my code with this problem, but a few `sym`-s sprinkled around solved those too.